# String contains versus List contains

Tags: java, string, list

I am writing an application that processes names. I want to achieve that if the items in the list contain "exactly" the same characters then should return true. Additionally, if the input contains the "exact" name followed by characters after the name or before then return true. For example for the input "Sid" return true, for input "iiSidee" return true, but "id" return false.

I would prefer that I use the list implementation but that is not achieving my requirement. However, if I choose String.contains(...) this works perfectly well. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
public static boolean list(String input) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Sid");
    list.add("Siddu");
    list.add("Kapil");

**EDIT:**
String[] inputs = input.split(" ");
// for every input item check in list

for(int = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   if(inputs[i].contains(list) {
       return true;
   }
   else {
      return false;
  }
}

**ORIGINAL:**

    if(list.contains(input)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Regular expressions seem like they would be useful for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input are space separated words, use nested for-loops to check if any of the list's elements is contained in any of the words.

```
for (String x : list) {
    for (String y : input.split(" ")) {
        if (x.contains(y)) return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Yes, it is space separated words - that is a great idea. Is there not any other way to avoid having 2 loops?

Comment: Yes, probably it can be done in one line with Java 8 Streams, but seems way easier to me using classic for-loops.

Answer (score 2):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(list("Sid"));
        System.out.println(list("Siddu"));
        System.out.println(list("iiSidee"));
        System.out.println(list("id"));
        System.out.println(list("aaaKapil"));
        System.out.println(list("Kapil"));
        System.out.println(list("ii"));
    }

    public static boolean list(String input) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Sid");
        list.add("Siddu");
        list.add("Kapil");
        for (String s : list) {
            if (s != null && input != null) {
                if (input.equals(s) || input.contains(s)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
false
true
true
false
```

---

**[Update]** Adding this update to clear @lainatnavi's doubt

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (long i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
            "hello".equals("hello");
        System.out.println("Time taken: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms");

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (long i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
            "hello".contains("hello");
        System.out.println("Time taken: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Time taken: 498 ms
Time taken: 6405 ms
```

The reason why I have done `if (input.equals(s) || input.contains(s))` in my answer is that if `input.equals(s)` returns `true`, the control won't go to check `input.contains(s)` which will be a performance benefit.

Comment: (true || true) is always true. (false || false) is always false

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash - this kind of matches it. Basically, it is the other way around. I need to first split on the inputs and for each input check whether it is contained in the list.

Comment: @lainatnavi - `true || false` is `true`. Also, `false || true` is `true`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash the comment was referring to this line `input.equals(s) || input.contains(s)`. There's no need to check `input.equals(s)` if you combine the result with `input.contains(s)` with the OR operator.

Comment: @lainatnavi - I have added an update to clear your doubt. I hope, it helps.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash yes, now I understand the reason behind that check. I guess it's because the jvm will first compare the pointers to the strings in the `equals` case and conclude for equality.

Answer (score 0):

this might be the problem, you are not comparing every item in the list, you should do something like this:

```
public static boolean list(String input) {
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Sid");
list.add("Siddu");
list.add("Kapil");

for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if(list.get(i).contains(input)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. This works! However, I need to split each input and I need to check whether that input is contained within the list. I want to avoid 2 seperate loops. Is this possible? So basically for every input check whether it is contained in the list i.e. "aaaKapil" returns true, "Kapil" returns true, "il" returns false.

Comment: @SidKumar from the original question it seems you need to check if any of the elements of the list is contained in the input string, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with a stream (Java 8). Also, If you will have big data you can increase the performance with its help.

```
public static boolean list(String input) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Sid");
    list.add("Siddu");
    list.add("Kapil");
    return list.stream().anyMatch(item -> item.equals(input) || input.contains(item));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression [S][I][D], with this code boolean b3 = Pattern.matches("[S][I][D]");